# PHP Oracle 10g very slow fetch

Tags: php, performance, oracle, oracle10g, oci8

I'm not used to use Oracle, so I may not ask my question really well.

I execute very simple `SELECT` queries from an Linux Apache server with PHP 5.3 (PECL Oci8 1.4.6, client 11.2.0.3.0) to an Oracle server (10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0), which I'm not the admin of.

The `oci_parse` and `oci_execute` take less than a millisecond, but the `oci_fetch_array`s that I do right after this are REALLY slow (sometimes more than a second).

At first, I tried changing the `SELECT *` by `SELECT [all the columns I need]`, but it's still slow.

What should I look to ?

Comment: How many columns are being returned and what kind of datatypes are they?

Comment: The biggest table has nearly 100, but the same problem with less columns. Data types are date, number, varchar2, clob.

Comment: Is it possible that your bottleneck is really the network?  The fetch will grab rows from server to client, my guess is that they are not on same subnet (remote hosting your server?)

Comment: I thought it was this before, but when I'm browsing the data with a tool such as Adminer (on the same Apache server), the data is shown very quickly compared to my queries.

Comment: I've experienced the same on a 10g. Explain Plan was okay. Loading with SQLDeveloper was ok. But loading on the webserver was slow. Profiling showed `oci_fetch_*` to be the culprit. I think it has to do with the LOBs, but didn't find a solution to it though.

Comment: I have LOBs, but their reading is pretty quick. I googled a lot about "oci fetch slow", but didn't get any clue :(

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
oci_set_prefetch($statement_id, 1000);
```

... or increase your `oci8.default_prefetch` value in php.ini.

Comment: I wanted to do it, but it is only supported by Oracle 11g (I'm with 10g)

Comment: Unless you're using cursors - it shouldn't require 11g and it really depends on the Oracle Instant Client, for which you said is version 11.2.0.3.0. It should work. :)

Comment: I already have oci8.default_prefetch = 100 in php.ini, and all the fetches take nearly the same time (from the first to the last)

Comment: I tweaked the various oci settings in my setup as well and it did improve the situation somewhat, but it was still much slower than it should be imo. `oci_fetch_*` would still be extremely slow.